# Heroku review app deploy with github: how to change the user deploying

Tags: heroku, github

I inherited a Heroku account. We moved to a team setup and I'm getting started with review apps.

When trying to create a review app, Heroku complains:

> Cannot create this review app • Your role collab on the team xxxxx is
>   not allowed to perform that action.

However, I'm an admin on Heroku.
Another admin tried also and had the same problem.

The deploys prior to moving to a team, seems to have been initiated by another user, who is a collaborator, but I know for certain that the user did not actually trigger the deploy, the *activity* shows as being initiated by this user however it was triggered by the owner of the (then) personal app clicking `create review app`.

I'm trying to understand how the deploy activity is linked to the github account, so my first question is:

**Is the deploy activity associated with a specific Github user? If so, where/how is the user defined?**

I get the impression I need to disconnect the Github account from the pipeline, and re-connect with one of the admin's accounts, but I'm wary of disconnecting without understanding the consequences: the Heroku help on that is not clear at all.

My second question is:

**What happens when I disconnect the Github account from the pipeline? Should I worry that it will mess up my running dynos? If not in disconnecting, could it cause trouble on re-connection?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do this was to un-link the github capability in Heroku, and re-link with the account I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently. I had set up a pipeline in Heroku with review apps using an old Heroku account. I later wanted to remove that old account's access to the Heroku apps and I ran into the same issue you did.

Here's what I did.

1. I unlinked github from the pipeline. This deleted all existing review apps. But it left the staging and production apps alone and in their stages in the pipeline.
2. Then I re-linked github to the pipeline using the more permanent Heroku account.
3. And I had to re-set up the review apps configuration in the pipeline.

At that point, I had to recreate all review apps that existed before I started.